# Azure Data Factory Delete Activity - Will not delete folder

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

ADF has Storage Blob Data Contributor access which gives write permissions.
I have the delete activity setup the same as the Microsoft guide below (second example)

- No file name specified
- Recursive = true
  But only the files within the folder are deleted and not the folder.

I tried running the delete activity on an empty folder as well and it did not work.  It will first succeed and say that it has deleted the 1 file (i.e. the empty folder).  Then I run the pipeline again and it will say the blob cannot be found.  So ADF does sort of think that its deleting the folder, but the folder is still there in storage explorer.

Any advice? Thanks!

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity#examples-of-using-the-delete-activity]

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1_delete",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Delete1",
                "type": "Delete",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DS_BinaryDeleteFolder",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "enableLogging": false,
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Say you want to delete `folder2` which contains files and sub folders as in 2nd example, then giving `recursive=True` and path as `folder1/folder2`, then running delete is deleting complete folder2. If folder2, contains only files, then the folder2 is not getting deleted (only files are deleted). But when I rerun with the same path, folder gets deleted.

Comment: "But when I rerun with the same path, folder gets deleted. " --> Can you please share your json for the activity and the dataset so I can maybe see what I've got wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please confirm this: Is the folder only showing in Storage explorer after deleting? Or in the storage account (azure portal) as well?

Comment: Considering you are using Azure datalake gen2 storage, Can you please try using the `storeSettings` type as `AzureBlobFSReadSettings` and check again?